# Arrays to store DateTime from Database

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to store the date from DateTime from PhpMyAdmin into an array in my code. For some reason, It only applies the last date to the position [0] from my array. Please help.

This is what I tried:

```
$id = $_SESSION['userId']; 
      $dBname = "infosensor";
      $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBname);

      $sql = "SELECT dias FROM `$id`;";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      if ($resultCheck > 0)
      {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

          $horario = $horario .'"'.(date('H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])))). '",';    

          $arr = array($horario);
        }
      }


      echo $arr[0];
```

The result that I get from the code I tried is:

```
"16:29:47","16:30:07","16:33:55","16:34:25",...
```

All of the at position [0]

I would need to when going into the array -> arr[0] = "16:29:47" when I want the position 1 I just use arr[1] = "16:30:07"...

Comment: Do you have a separate table for each user?

Comment: You keep overwriting `$arr`.

Comment: @mickmackusa How can I not overwrite it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing this line like this:

```
$horario = (date('H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias']))));
```

```
$arr[] = explode(',', $horario);
```

Comment: I'm getting the answer as 'Array' :(

Comment: I almost work, I don't want to print the whole array, just the position that I type

Comment: What does `echo $arr[0];` output now?

Comment: I get this Ola Array ( [0] => "16:29:47" [1], but when I need to get only position 1, It prints position 0 with it, I don't need pos 0 when I print pos 1

Comment: Change this `$horario = $horario .'"'.(date('H:i:s', str.....` to `$horario = (date('H:i:s', str....`

Comment: As you keep on adding old value (position 0) to beginning of new value (position 1)

Comment: Just A quick question, I'm getting the right output, but it is printing like this Array ( [0] => 16:34:41 ), do you know how could I only get the date?

Comment: Try adding [0] afterwards e.g. `echo $arr[0][0];` and `echo $arr[1][0];`

Answer (score -1):

First you need to initialise $arr = []
Then you can achieve this by explode.

```
$id = $_SESSION['userId']; 
$dBname = "infosensor";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBname);

$sql = "SELECT dias FROM `$id`;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$arr = [];
if ($resultCheck > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

        $horario = $horario .'"'.(date('H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])))). '",';
    }

    if(!empty($horario)){
        $arr = explode(',', $horario);
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: This worked but How can I access the Array? Is it like $arr[0]? And why is echo not working?

Comment: here you can directly access $arr; for try echo $arr[0]; // output: 16:29:47

Comment: answer is updated now @Matheus

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = []; // define array here
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

      $horario = $horario .'"'.(date('H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])))). '",';    

      $arr[] = $horario; // add [] here and remove array()
}
//    print_r($arr);
echo $arr[0];
```

**Output**

Like this

> arr[0] = "16:29:47" , arr[1] = "16:30:07"

Comment: Yes, But I want to get only the arr[1] for example, why does it show me the other ones

Comment: because you print the whole array that's why

Comment: MR. DV please say reason for it?

Comment: But I want just the position that I type, how can i get that?

Comment: i did not understand what you get from array if you want only `$arr[0]` than use it, whats the problem?

Comment: No, I have a bunch of dates, each of them is going to be displayed at different positions, that's why I don't want to print the whole array, just the position that I need

Comment: which position bro?

Comment: All of them, It will go into a loop further on, but your code prints this:```arr[0] = "16:29:47" , arr[1] = "16:30:07"

``` I need this: ``` arr[1] = "16:30:07"```

Comment: so you use `[]` inside `while loop` `$arr[]=` and its working

Comment: If I want the position 1, for some reason the position 0 comes with it... If I want position 2 the position 1 and 0 come with it, that the problem

Comment: and where you use this share exact code

Comment: I will use this code inside a chart, The code from moshe gross worked, I will paste so you can have a look, It was because of the way I was getting the values into the variable

Comment: and remove `array()` from code